# Python telebot создание многопользовательского бота

Tags: python, telebot

Подскажите пожалуйста, я написала бот с использованием reply кнопок. В начале человек должен ввести день, месяц и год рождения. С этими данными производятся математические операции и уже в зависимости от них, информация которая пишется на кнопках и в дальнейшем. Бот реализован весь по принципу, вначале приходит ответ на ввод данных с клавиатурой (Reply). На клавиатуре 4 основных подменю, и кнопка назад, которая ведет на старт. В подменю, тоже используются reply кнопки, и в зависимости от расчетов по первоначальной дате рождения, человек при нажатии получает свою информацию.

Вопрос простой, для тех у кого есть опыт. Если бот запускают с двух девайсов, и вводят разные данные, то первый пользователь уже видит данные второго. Как сделать, чтобы все данные уникальными для каждого пользователя, и не пересекались, не зависимо от того, кто еще использует бот? (пробовала с помощью классов и библиотеки не вышло)
буду благодарна за подсказку
Вот пример начала кода, функция matrix после вызова главного меню, показывает данные кторые ввел в это время другой пользователь на другом устройстве.

```
    import telebot
    from telebot import types
    
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('token');
    
    class User:
        def __init__(self, user_id):
            self.user_id = user_id
            self.day = None
            self.month = None
            self.year = None
            self.numbers = [''] * 9
        def set_day(self, day):
                self.day = day
    
        def set_month(self, month):
                self.month = month
    
        def set_year(self, year):
                self.year = year
    
        def get_numbers(self):
                return self.numbers
    users = {}
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
        user_id = message.from_user.id 
        users[user_id] = User(user_id)
        bot.send_message(user_id, "Введите день рождения:")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_day_messages);
        
    def get_day_messages(message):
        user_id = message.from_user.id 
        users[user_id].set_day(message.text)
        global day_str;
        day_str=message.text;
        bot.send_message(user_id, "введите номер месяца рождения:");
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_month_messages);
        
    
        
    def get_month_messages(message):
        user_id = message.from_user.id 
        users[user_id].set_month(message.text)
        global month_str;
        month_str=message.text;
        bot.send_message(user_id, "введите год рождения:");
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_year_messages);
            
            
    def get_year_messages(message):
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        users[user_id].set_year(message.text)
        username = message.from_user.username  # Получение ника пользователя (если доступно)
        first_name = message.from_user.first_name  # Получение имени пользователя
        last_name = message.from_user.last_name  # Получение фамилии пользователя
        
        user = users[user_id] 
        day_str = user.day
        month_str = user.month
        year_str = user.year
    
        #... вычесления с полученными переменными...
        
        
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
        keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['кнопка 1',  'кнопка 2', 'кнопка 3', 'кнопка 4', 'Расчитать новую дату']])
        
        
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://bs.krok.edu.ua/fileadmin/user_upload/leader5advices2017.jpg',caption=' тектс ',reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode="HTML")
        
        # дальнейшие расчеты.....#
            
        global numbers  # объявление и вычисление переменной number(одна из основных для будущих кнопокк и данных
        numbers=[]
        for i in range(9): numbers.append('')
        for i in range(9):
            ..... #  вычисление number....#
        
    def save_user_data(user_id, username,  first_name, last_name, day_str, month_str, year_str):
        
        #  запись в файл данных 
    
    def main_menu(message):
        user_id = message.from_user.id  # Получаем идентификатор пользователя
        if user_id not in users:
            users[user_id] = User(user_id)
        
        
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
        keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Кнопка 1',  'кнопка 2', 'кнопка 3', 'кнопка 4', 'Расчитать новую дату']])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Прожолжайте делать выбор, или выбирайте расчитать новую дату", reply_markup=keyboard)
    
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Кнопка 1")
    def matrix (message):
       
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        if user_id not in users:
            users[user_id] = User(user_id)
    
        user = users[user_id]
        numbers = user.get_numbers()  # Получаем список чисел пользователя
    
        for i in range(9):
            if numbers[i-1] == '':
                numbers[i-1] = '<'+str(i)+'>'
    
        keyboardM = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
        button_1 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[0])
        button_2 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[1])
        button_3 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[2])
        button_4 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[3])
        button_5 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[4])
        button_6 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[5])
        button_7 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[6])
        button_8 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[7])
        button_9 = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[8])
        button_back = types.KeyboardButton('в главное меню')
    
        keyboardM.row(button_1, button_4, button_7)
        keyboardM.row(button_2, button_5, button_8)
        keyboardM.row(button_3, button_6, button_9)
        keyboardM.row(button_back)
    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'текст определенный...', reply_markup=keyboardM)
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Answer (score 1):

Можешь создать базу данных в которой будут сохранятся айди пользователя и его ответы. Суть будет в том что бы при выводе каких либо данных(или их отсутствия) проверялась база данных, тогда не должно возникнуть проблем

Comment: для этого можно использовать например sqlite что бы не разворачивать mysql сервер или redis. Нужны будут библиотеки `sqlite3` и `aiosqlite`

создаёшь файл sqlite базы (например data.sqlite), и цепляешь его с помощью `DBCONNECT = "data.sqlite"`

Comment: запрос в бд осуществляешь таким образом:

`db = sqlite3.connect(DBCONNECT)`
`db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`
`c = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users where username <> '@None'")`

Comment: запись в бд: `db.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (name) values (?)", (m.text,))`

Answer (score -1):

лучше кнопки создавать так:

```
keyboardM = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
for i in range(8):
     button = types.KeyboardButton(numbers[I])
button_back = types.KeyboardButton('в главное меню')
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'текст определенный...', reply_markup=keyboardM)
```

а по поводу вопроса, то если честно я беспонятия, можешь попробовать

```
import telebot
import random
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
egg = {}  

START = range(1)  
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    srm = 0
    egg[srm] = START
    secret = random.randint(1,49494985894939494944)
    egg[srm] = START
    id1 = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш id {id}')
```